# Drop Down CSS error

Tags: jquery, html, css

I recently installed a drop down menu buts it's not working. This also happens on other pages with text below. What is causing this and how can I correct it?

I've been working om this drop down menu thing for a while now and decided I'm not able to do it by myself. I've googled many solutions and seen a couple of youtube tutorials for css drop down menus but somehow they always work for the person in question but not for me.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z04w2wo0/)

```css
    .logo {
      float: left;
      background: #FFF;
      padding: 28px 29px 19px 30px;
    }
    .top-nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }
    .top-nav ul li a {
      background: #fff;
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 40px 47.6px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      color: #32332e;
      font-size: 0.875em;
      transition: 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
      -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
      margin: 0 -1px;
      border-left: 1px solid #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .top-nav li.active> a,
    .top-nav li> a:hover {
      color: #FFF;
      background: #404642;
    }
    .top-nav {
      float: right;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .main-header {
      margin-top: 16px;
      background: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="images/logo2.png" title="logo" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="top-nav">

    <span class="menu"></span>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Mission</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <ul style="padding: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 48px;
          left: 0;
          width: 150px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          -moz-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
          display: none;opacity: 0;
          visibility: hidden;
          -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
          -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -o-transition: opacity 0.2s; -transition: opacity 0.2s;">
          <li style=" background: #555; 
          display: block; 
          color: #fff;
          text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;"><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: A Demo with the CSS extracted to a proper stylesheet (perhaps in JSfiddle) would be useful. I do notice that the parent `li`  don't seem to have `position:relative` though.

Comment: there is no dropdown menu in your code

Comment: I'm assuming that you want the child menus below "Services" to be displayed when Services is hovered?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z04w2wo0/  I NEED A DROP DOWN MENU BUT ITS FAILED

Comment: have you want something like [**this**](https://goo.gl/KswYPU) ?

PS: its just a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove css code inside your child ul and add two css class in your css file. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/o8mevrmg/)

```
.top-nav li:hover ul{
        display:block ;
    }
    .top-nav li ul{
        padding: 0;     
        position:absolute;
       display:none;
      width: 150px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      -moz-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.2s; -transition: opacity 0.2s;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking from the supplied code, it looks like you've copied / pasted a "dirty" layout ( *layout that's been interacted with* ) from another site

The UL element nested below the Services has a lot of inline styles - which is probably a result of Javascript injection during when its parent element was hovered.

Best to remove all these inline styles and give it another go.

Comment: its a part of a theme but need a drop down

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this -

```css
.logo {
      float: left;
      background: #FFF;
      padding: 28px 29px 19px 30px;
    }
    .top-nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    .top-nav ul li a {
      background: #fff;
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 40px 47.6px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      color: #32332e;
      font-size: 0.875em;
      transition: 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
      -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
      margin: 0 -1px;
      border-left: 1px solid #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .top-nav li.active> a,
    .top-nav li> a:hover {
      color: #FFF;
      background: #404642;
    }
    .top-nav {
      float: right;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .main-header {
      margin-top: 16px;
      background: #fff;
    }

    .top-nav > ul > li > ul{
     padding: 0;
          position: absolute;
          /*top: 48px;*/
          left: 0;
          width: 150px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          -moz-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
          display: none;
          /*visibility: hidden;*/
          -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
          -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
          -o-transition: opacity 0.2s; -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }
     .top-nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
     }
```

```html
 <div class="main-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="images/logo2.png" title="logo" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="top-nav">

    <span class="menu"></span>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Mission</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
          <a href='#'>Product 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```